# Solve $y'' / y = 3\sin^2 x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how to solve ODE $$y'' / y = 3\sin^2 x$$? I'm a bit stuck here as $y''/y$ could not transform to a more useful form to make use of $\ln y$ or anything else...

Comment: This is a [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation) $y''(x)=f(x)y(x)$ with periodic $f$. In general there is no simple solution.

Comment: You can also see [this][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function].

Comment: You get a specific case of Mathieu's differential equation after multiplying both sides by $y$, then using the trigonometric identity:
$$3\sin^2(x)=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\cos(2x)$$